# bindParam with md5() column PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, md5

I try to compare user password what lay inside database and with that what comes from login form, but when I do this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = :username, password = :password)');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', md5($_POST['password']));
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch(); // return false
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password

Comment: And `bindParam` binds a variable, use `bindValue` instead.

Comment: **Danger**: “MD5" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: basic sql debugging: if your query calls return false (aka "failure"), then get the error message: `die($dbh->errorInfo())`. If you'd done this, you'd have been told about the syntax error in your query. **NEVER** assume success with a DB operation. always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = :username AND password = :password)
```

Answer (score 2):

your query is wrong.
Try this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your query right. Use the code below

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', md5($_POST['password']));
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch(); // return false
```

Hope this helps you